# Format edittext as xxx-xx-xxxx in android

Tags: android

am developing an simple application.In which EditText get number input from user.i want to display the number in XXX-XX-XXXX format instead of XXXXXXXXX format.is there any way to achieve it..Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Use this [class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long time i got it by using this code.

fix the lines in edittext xml

```
android:maxLength="11"
```

now try this code

```
    final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        int cursorPosition = 0;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            edittext.removeTextChangedListener(this);

            try {
                cursorPosition = edittext.getSelectionStart();
                if (editable.length() > 0) {

                    String tempIp = "";
                    String newIp = "";
                    String strIp = edittext.getText().toString();
                    String tempParamArr[] = strIp.split("-");
                    if (tempParamArr.length > 0) {
                        cursorPosition -= (tempParamArr.length - 1);
                        for (int i = 0; i < tempParamArr.length; i++) {
                            tempIp += tempParamArr[i];
                        }
                    } else {
                        tempIp = strIp;
                    }

                    for (int count = 0; count < tempIp.length(); count++) {
                        if (count == 3 || count == 5) {
                            newIp += "-";
                            newIp += tempIp.charAt(count);
                            cursorPosition++;
                        } else {
                            newIp += tempIp.charAt(count);
                        }
                    }
                    edittext.setText(newIp);
                    if (newIp.length() > cursorPosition)
                        edittext.setSelection(cursorPosition);
                    else
                        edittext.setSelection(newIp.length());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            edittext.addTextChangedListener(this);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this may help you,

```
EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher());
```

NumberTextWatcher - handles auto inserting dashes and auto removing dashes if the user is deleting:

```
public class NumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private boolean isFormatting;
    private boolean deletingHyphen;
    private int hyphenStart;
    private boolean deletingBackward;

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
        if (isFormatting)
            return;

        isFormatting = true;

        // If deleting hyphen, also delete character before or after it
        if (deletingHyphen && hyphenStart > 0) {
            if (deletingBackward) {
                if (hyphenStart - 1 < text.length()) {
                    text.delete(hyphenStart - 1, hyphenStart);
                }
            } else if (hyphenStart < text.length()) {
                text.delete(hyphenStart, hyphenStart + 1);
            }
        }
        if (text.length() == 3 || text.length() == 7) {
            text.append('-');
        }

        isFormatting = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        if (isFormatting)
            return;

        // Make sure user is deleting one char, without a selection
        final int selStart = Selection.getSelectionStart(s);
        final int selEnd = Selection.getSelectionEnd(s);
        if (s.length() > 1 // Can delete another character
                && count == 1 // Deleting only one character
                && after == 0 // Deleting
                && s.charAt(start) == '-' // a hyphen
                && selStart == selEnd) { // no selection
            deletingHyphen = true;
            hyphenStart = start;
            // Check if the user is deleting forward or backward
            if (selStart == start + 1) {
                deletingBackward = true;
            } else {
                deletingBackward = false;
            }
        } else {
            deletingHyphen = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it works..by changing if (text.length() == 3 || text.length() == 6)instead of if (text.length() == 3 || text.length() == 7) .

Answer (score 0):

Use PhoneNumberUtils which format you number :

```
String formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(unformattedNumber);
```

Take a look at [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html) for more options.